# PHP select is not displaying any value

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display a table from my database in a dropdown menu. i already         made the connection, did the query but nothing is appearing in the dropdown. can anyone tell me why.

below is my code:

```
<?php 
    include ('db_connect.php');
    $sql ="select ins_name from institution";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);                         
    echo "<select name='ins_name'>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<option value='".$row['ins_name']."'>"."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>"
?>
```

Comment: mixing `mysql with mysqli` in your code!!

Comment: ou are using `mysqli` and `mysql` the same time, it is right?

Answer (score 0):

First, you mixed `mysql_*` with `mysqli_*` extension. It would be advisable to just use `mysqli_*` rather than the [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) `mysql_*`.

Assuming that you establish your connection to your database using `mysqli_*` extension (*db_connect.php*):

```
$conn = new mysqli("Host", "Username", "Password", "Database"); /* REPLACE NECESSARY PARAMETERS */

/* CHECK CONNECTION */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
```

Then your main file:

```
<?php 

    include ('db_connect.php');

    echo '<select name="ins_name">';

    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT ins_name FROM institution"); /* PREPARE QUERY */
    $stmt->execute(); /* EXECUTE QUERY */
    $stmt->bind_result($insname); /* BIND RESULT TO THIS VARIABLE */
    while($stmt->fetch()){ /* GET ALL RESULT */

        echo '<option value="'.$insname.'">'.$insname.'</option>'; 

    } /* END OF WHILE LOOP */
    $stmt->close(); /* CLOSE STATEMENT */

    echo '</select>';

?>
```

And also, you did not set a data to display inside your `<option>` in your example. You can see above how we concat the value in your `<option></option>`

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysqli_fetch_array()` and You need to write name between option tag.

For e.g `<option value="1">Test</option>`

```
<?php 
    include ('db_connect.php');
    $sql ="select ins_name from institution";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);                         
    echo "<select name='ins_name'>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<option value='".$row['ins_name']."'>".$row['ins_name']."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>"
?>
```

Comment: welcome.. glade to help you. Accept the answer if its useful. @ash_dev15

Answer (score 0):

You need to use mysqli. Olso you have to display the value in the option,

```
<?php 
    include ('db_connect.php');
    $sql = "select ins_name from institution";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);                         
    echo "<select name='ins_name'>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $insName =  $row['ins_name'];
        echo "<option value='".$insName."'>".$insName."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>"
?>
```